# How to pass input html data to a javascript function as its variables and get a response

Tags: javascript, html

**My problem**: I can't get to pass the input data from html to js function as its variables and get the appropriate response.

**My goal**: when the user clics on submit button he receives whatever response the js function provided.

I have two files in the same directory:
- index.html
- index.js

**index.js content**:

```
function quEq(a, b, c) {
var delta = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c);
  if (a == 0) {
  return "Not a quadratic equation";
  };
if (delta < 0) {
    return "Complex root! No solution in real numbers";
    } else {
        var first= (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
        var second= (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
        return {first, second};
        };
};
```

**index.html content**:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>Quadratic Equation</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="bg-red-400">
                <div class="">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Enter 'a' value</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="a" placeholder="1">
                      <label>Enter 'b' value</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="b" placeholder="5">
                      <label>Enter 'c' value</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="c" placeholder="6">
                      <button onclick="quEq(document.getElementById('a').nodeValue, document.getElementById('b').value, document.getElementById('c').value)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                  </form>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP 
I HOPE I AM NOT BREAKING ANY RULES

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick event handler should successfully handle the click event, but it isn't clear what you want to do with the return value of your function. The browser will not do anything by default. Instead, you need to manage this yourself.

For example, you could write the results into some other part of the DOM.

In your HTML you can create some nodes to hold the output:

```
<div id="result-1" />
<div id="result-2" />
```

Then in your event handler:

```
document.getElementById('result-1').innerText = first;
document.getElementById('result-2').innerText = second;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a variety of HTML and JavaScript syntax errors.

See comments in the code below:

```js
// Get references to the DOM elements that you'll work with
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var c = document.getElementById('c');

// Do event binding in JavaScript, not with inline HTML attributes
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Use "value", not "nodeValue"
  quEq(a.value, b.value, c.value);
});

function quEq(a, b, c) {
  // Carefull with syntax!
  var delta = (b * 2) - (4 * a * c);
  if (a == 0) {
    // return doesn't show up anywhere
    alert("Not a quadratic equation");
  } else if (delta < 0) {
    alert("Complex root! No solution in real numbers");
  } else {
    var first= (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
    var second= (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
    alert(first + " " + second);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>Quadratic Equation</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="bg-red-400">
                <div class="">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="a">Enter 'a' value</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="a" placeholder="1">
                      <label for="b">Enter 'b' value</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="b" placeholder="5">
                      <label for="c">Enter 'c' value</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="c" placeholder="6">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The followng line doesn't have a closing tag and so is invalid. -->
                    <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
                  </form>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two flaws in this code

1)

```
document.getElementById('a').nodeValue
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('a').value
```

2) you should be aware that placeholder is just a text, it seems strange that you can see 6 but there's no number yet, so instead of placeholder set value attribute directly if you want some default numbers

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="a" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

*Now its working*

```
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
  b: <input type="number" name="b" id="b"><br>
  c: <input type="number" name="c" id="c"><br>
  <button onclick="quEq(document.getElementById('a').value,document.getElementById('b').value,document.getElementById('c').value)">Submit</button>

<script>
    function quEq(a, b, c) {
    var delta = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c);
    if (a == 0) {
        alert("Not a quadratic equation");
    };
    if (delta < 0) {
        alert("Complex root! No solution in real numbers");
    } else {
        var first= (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
        var second= (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
        alert(first, second);
    };
    };
</script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things in your index.html file that are not correct, for example, you opened a second div with a class "form-group" yet you did not close it, also you did not pass properly the value for "a" (.nodeValue when it should be .value).

I made some changes to your code and appended the response in the div you weren't using (the second "form-group") and changed it's name, also I added type="button" to your button so it won't submit as soon as you click on it, [you can find the html and js in codepen](https://codepen.io/jrodri06/pen/eYmEydJ)

Here is your function:

```
function quEq() {
 var a = document.getElementById('a').value
 var b = document.getElementById('b').value
 var c = document.getElementById('c').value

 var delta = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)

 if (a == 0) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerHTML = "Not a quadratic equation"
 }

 if (delta < 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerHTML = "Complex root! No solution in real numbers"
 } 
 else {
   var first= (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2*a)
   var second= (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
   document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerHTML = first + ", " + second
 }
}
```

Here is your div changed:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="bg-red-400">
            <div>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter 'a' value</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="a" placeholder="1" value="1"/>

                        <label>Enter 'b' value</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="b" placeholder="5" value="5" />

                        <label>Enter 'c' value</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="c" placeholder="6" value="6" />

                        <button onclick="quEq()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info"></div>
                </form>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I added a value property to your inputs since you seemed to be using the value you assign to the placeholder. If that's not the behaviour you want, you can remove the value property but I also recommend removing the placeholder as it can be miss leading.